# Javascript nesting switch statement

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and I am learning about switch statements. My code is trying to run two tiers of switch statements and validating data. My desired output would be to have the user input either a YES or a NO and if YES is selected then it will go through the switch statement however if anything other than YES is selected then it will output "Too Bad!" to the console. I am having compiler errors and I am not sure how to fix this because I don't fully understand javascript syntax to the fullest.

```
var user = prompt("Welcome to learning about exceptions with me, A-rod. 
In this tutorial we will be learning about exceptions and what not 
to do with them. Let's get started, shall we? ").toUpperCase(); 

switch(user){
    case 'YES'
     var user_1 = prompt("What's your name?"); 
     switch(user_1) {
        case 'Buster':
            console.log("Hey, brother!");
            break;
        case 'Alex':
            console.log("I've made a huge mistake.");
            break;
        case 'Steve':
            console.log("Steve Holt!");
            break;
     default:
         console.log("I don't know you!");}
break; 
default:
    console.log("too bad!"); 
 }
```

The errors are

> "expecting ':' instead of 'var' "

and

> "expecting '(end)' instead of 'default' "

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon for your first case.

Comment: When you look properly, console also points to row where error is happening.. (mostly)

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a semi-colon for your first switch statement:

```js
var user = prompt("Welcome to learning about exceptions with me, A-rod. In this tutorial we will be learning about exceptions and what not to do with them. Let's get started, shall we? ").toUpperCase(); 

switch(user){
    case 'YES':
     var user_1 = prompt("What's your name?"); 
     switch(user_1) {
        case 'Buster':
            console.log("Hey, brother!");
            break;
        case 'Alex':
            console.log("I've made a huge mistake.");
            break;
        case 'Steve':
            console.log("Steve Holt!");
            break;
     default:
         console.log("I don't know you!");}
break; 
default:
    console.log("too bad!"); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var user = prompt("Welcome to learning about exceptions with me, A-rod." + 
"In this tutorial we will be learning about exceptions and what not" +  
"to do with them. Let's get started, shall we? ").toUpperCase(); 

switch(user){
    case 'YES':
     var user_1 = prompt("What's your name?"); 
     switch(user_1) {
        case 'Buster':
            console.log("Hey, brother!");
            break;
        case 'Alex':
            console.log("I've made a huge mistake.");
            break;
        case 'Steve':
            console.log("Steve Holt!");
            break;
     default:
         console.log("I don't know you!");
         break;
     }
break;
default:
    console.log("too bad!"); 
    break;
 }
```

Comment: You forget the colon after case yes, to concatenate the string after each line, and break add an break statement after the default case.